Prepping produce before Pesach
Here's the scenario: A person kashered their entire fridge for Pesach. They did not kasher a stainless steel colander which they used to rinse off produce (e.g. carrots, lemons, potatoes, etc.) with cold, running water. Then, they took the rinsed produce and put it in the fridge. This all happened a few days before Pesach.

Was the produce made not kosher for Pesach because it was rinsed off using the colander?

Was the fridge made not kosher for Pesach by putting the produce in it?



Hi and welcome to MI Yodeya! This site does not offer rulings on specific cases. Please consult an Orthodox Rabbi.
